# How to open mat tree upward when expanded instead of expanding downward in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented mat tree, when I expand it will open in downward and the children display below parent node. But the requirement is when I expand it, it needs to open in upward and children display above parent. Can anyone please help?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m77g7e-semvxp?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts